# convertin nested json to string with vb.net and json.net

Tags: json, vb.net, facebook, json.net

Iäam a newbaby with json and trying to read facebook json to vb.net with coal to save it to database.

```
{
    "id": "1154546722",
    "name": "Toni Laket",
    "first_name": "Toni",
    "last_name": "Laket",
    "link": "https://www.facebook.com/tbll",
    "username": "arbous",
    "birthday": "07/11/1969",
    "hometown": {
        "id": "1031215454756",
        "name": "Harmo, Land"
    },
    "location": {
        "id": "1031215454756",
        "name": "Harmo, Land"
    },
    "work": [
        {
            "employer": {
                "id": "5440547873",
                "name": "Sytyty Oy"
            },
            "location": {
                "id": "107234324406",
                "name": "Pori"
            },
            "position": {
                "id": "14625323232414",
                "name": "Keaxrrjohtaja"
            },
            "start_date": "1999-01-01"
        }
    ],
    "education": [
        {
            "school": {
                "id": "106444432115435",
                "name": "ukio"
            },
            "type": "High School"
        }
    ],
    "gender": "male",
    "email": "tddd@arpo.com",
    "timezone": 3,
    "locale": "fi_FI",
    "verified": true,
    "updated_time": "2013-10-09T05:32:47+0000"
}
```

So I'am trying to get all that information to database table. I have manged to save basic things like email, name etc.

What about location, hometown and work? how do I fetch that information?

I have been trying to find simple solution to this for 2-day now. I pretty sure that someone has done this facebook fetch before me with vb.net (v4.0)?

I have been using json.net with this but haven't managed to get those nested json fields. How do i fetch those nested field with json.net and in vb.net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're already getting the name and e-mail, you can't be that far off.  Here's how I would do it:

First, create a hierarchy of classes corresponding to your JSON:

```
Public Class Person
    Public Property id As String
    Public Property name As String
    Public Property first_name As String
    Public Property last_name As String
    Public Property link As String
    Public Property username As String
    Public Property birthday As String
    Public Property hometown As Hometown
    Public Property location As Location
    Public Property work As List(Of Work)
    Public Property education As List(Of Education)
    Public Property gender As String
    Public Property email As String
    Public Property timezone As Integer
    Public Property locale As String
    Public Property verified As Boolean
    Public Property updated_time As String
End Class

Public Class Hometown
    Public Property id As String
    Public Property name As String
End Class

Public Class Location
    Public Property id As String
    Public Property name As String
End Class

Public Class Work
    Public Property employer As Employer
    Public Property location As Location
    Public Property position As Position
    Public Property start_date As String
End Class

Public Class Employer
    Public Property id As String
    Public Property name As String
End Class

Public Class Position
    Public Property id As String
    Public Property name As String
End Class

Public Class Education
    Public Property school As School
    Public Property type As String
End Class

Public Class School
    Public Property id As String
    Public Property name As String
End Class
```

Next, deserialize the JSON into your classes like this:

```
Dim person As Person = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Person)(json)
```

Finally, use the data as you see fit.

```
Console.WriteLine("name: " + person.name)
Console.WriteLine("email: " + person.email)
Console.WriteLine("gender: " + person.gender)
Console.WriteLine("birthday: " + person.birthday)
Console.WriteLine("hometown: " + person.hometown.name)
Console.WriteLine("work:")
For Each work As Work In person.work
    Console.WriteLine(vbTab + "employer: " + work.employer.name)
    Console.WriteLine(vbTab + "position: " + work.position.name)
    Console.WriteLine(vbTab + "location: " + work.location.name)
    Console.WriteLine(vbTab + "start date: " + work.start_date)
Next
Console.WriteLine("education:")
For Each education As Education In person.education
    Console.WriteLine(vbTab + "school: " + education.school.name)
    Console.WriteLine(vbTab + "type: " + education.type)
Next
```

Example output:

```
name: Toni Laket
email: tddd@example.org
gender: male
birthday: 07/11/1969
hometown: Harmo, Land
work:
        employer: Sytyty Oy
        position: Keaxrrjohtaja
        location: Pori
        start date: 1999-01-01
education:
        school: ukio
        type: High School
```